# pyqt5 dialog not showing any widgets

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have created a dialog with Qt Creator and then translated the .ui file to .py file with

```
 pyuic5 dialog.ui -o dialog.py
```

The resulting code is the following

```
class Ui_dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog):
        dialog.setObjectName("dialog")
        dialog.resize(976, 725)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(dialog)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 210, 160, 80))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.retranslateUi(dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("dialog", "PushButton"))
```

Now I'm trying to display the dialog from my main window with

```
dialog = QDialog()
dialog.ui = Ui_dialog()
dialog.ui.setupUi(self)
dialog.show()
dialog.exec_()
```

The dialog is shown, but it's empty so there's no button or any other widgets I tried!?

Comment: You didn't set a layout. Your are creating the widgets but not adding them to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ui_Dialog's setupUi method requires a widget to fill in, and in your case you should change the following:

```
dialog.ui.setupUi(self)
```

to:

```
dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
```